# Max connection on a specific Application

Tags: connection, application, web-services, websphere

I've an application ( that contain some Web Services ) deployed on a Server in a WAS 7 environement. That server host a many application; what I'm looking for is a way to limit the number of connection for a specific application and not for entire server.

Ty in advice

Answer (score 0):

My standard guidance here is if you want this level of isolation, just use two JVMs.

It's unclear if you care about TCP connections or concurrent requests.  The only way to limit either of these is to create a new TCP endpoint and assign it to a new, non-default threadpool.

You would then map the special app to a new virtual host that only has a host alias that matches the new TCP port.

But this only works for clients that connect directly to the server -- if you connect via the WAS Plugin, a generated WAS plugin will never handle this separation correctly.  YOu could probably get it to work in a generic HTTP proxy or by heavily editing plugin-cfg.xml.